# Multiple inheritance casting from base class to a different derived class

Tags: c++, casting, multiple-inheritance

I have got the following set of classes:

[image]

And the following piece of code:

```
A* a;
if(condition)
{
    a = new E();
}
else
{
    a = new D();
}
```

Now given that there is such function as `F::foo()`, in order to call it, I have to cast `a` to either `E*` or `D*`:

```
if(condition)
{
    ((E*)a)->foo();
}
else
{
    ((D*)a)->foo();
}
```

As far as I know, casting `a` to `F*` in order to call `F::foo` would be illegal since `a` is of type `A*`; and to me, checking a condition before calling `foo`, sounds like a design problem. Could somebody please give some advice as to how I can improve this class hierarchy?

p.s. Used [this tool](http://yuml.me/diagram/scruffy/class/draw) to draw the diagram.

Comment: You need dynamic polymorphism through virtual functions and then the implementation will do all the hard work of calling the right function.

Comment: Out of interest, why did you assign your `new E()` to an `A*` in the first place? Several different approaches are discussed in the answers below. Some of them change your existing class hierarchy, others don't. It might be that the answer to this question about `A*` leads to a particular solution.

Comment: @SteveJessop I should of used a common base class, which was either `A` or `F` to instantiate `E` and `D`. The answers suggesting `F` could derive from `A` or vice versa do not meet my design requirements since the functionality of `F` and `A` is irrelevant. `F` is not an interface and both `E` and `D` need to inherit from it. I think I could also choose `F` as the common base class, but then I should have cast `a` to `A`, `C` or `B` when needed. So far your answer seems to be the best solution.

Comment: If `F` isn't an interface, then why does the code that receives the `A*` expect it to have a function named `Foo` at all? My proposed class `G` gives it a reason to expect that, or another route is to give up on polymorphism, accept that what it wants is "a `D` or a `E`", and just pass it a `boost::variant<D*,E*>`. That's a last resort, but it might be the only correct description of your design. If your design is that the function must be passed either a `D` or an `E`, then passing it an `A*` just because `A` happens to be a common base of the two doesn't reflect the design.

Comment: @SteveJessop Using class `G` is a great idea too. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>

struct A { virtual ~A() {} };

struct C : virtual A {};

struct B : virtual A {};

struct F {
    virtual void Foo() { std::cout << "ok\n"; }
};

struct E : C, virtual F {};

struct D : B, virtual F {};


int main() {
    A *a = new E();
    dynamic_cast<F*>(a)->Foo();
}
```

- If you mess up and the referand of `a` is not an instance of `F`, then the dynamic_cast returns null
- If you don't use virtual inheritance then you can end up with ambiguous base classes. A `dynamic_cast` to an ambiguous base will fail (return null). In this example there are no ambiguous bases, but you have to be aware of it.
- I've left out the virtual destructors on most of the classes, but only because I'm lazy.

If you repeatedly find yourself dealing with objects that are instances of both `A` and `F` then that should be reflected in the class hierarchy if possible. For example you might define a type `G` that inherits virtually from both `A` and `F`. Then `D` and `E` can inherit from `G` instead of `F`, and you can pass a `G*` to this code that expects an `A*` on which it can call `Foo()`.

Comment: Exactly, I also just tried this - on gcc, even the C-style cast from the question works - would that be UB?

Comment: @Andreas: The `static_cast` to `E*` and `D*` are OK (but of course you need to be able to evaluate the same condition as from when the object was created, to cast to the correct type). You can't `static_cast` from `A*` to `F*` though, because they're unrelated classes.

Comment: @Andreas: just realised, I didn't actually answer your question! The C-style cast to `E*` or `D*` is a `static_cast`, so it has defined behavior. A C-style cast to `F*` would be a `reinterpret_cast` because of the non-existence of the `static_cast`, and *that* would provoke UB when used to call `Foo()`.

Comment: You don't need the virtual inheritance in this case.

Comment: Thanks a lot - I also just had to re-read the question which I misinterpreted partially before - anyway, +1 for the good answer and the good explanations!

Comment: @user1610015: thanks, I noticed that too (eventually) and I've edited. Virtual inheritance *is* required for my proposed type `G`, if we want to prevent `A` being ambiguous. I got way ahead of myself :-)

Comment: @Andreas Do _not_, ever use C style classes within an inheritance hierarchy.  Depending on the case, it will sometimes result in a `static_cast` (OK if the pointed to object really is of the type in question), sometimes a `reinterpret_cast` (in which case, using the resulting pointer is undefined behavior---and in cases where multiple inheritance is involved, will probably do strange things).

Comment: @SteveJessop I hadn't thought of the additional (interface) class `G`, but it's also a good idea (if you can't consider `F` an extension of `A`).

Comment: @JamesKanze: mind you, it has taken 10 minutes to convince myself that you really can call virtual functions of `A` via a `G*` and get the override defined in (for example) `C` ;-) So the details are a bit complex, but the motivation is simple -- if we want something that's both an A and an F then we should define for ourselves a polymorphic interface that says exactly what we want. You're right, though, if `F` is designed to extend `A` then it should just virtually inherit it.

Comment: @SteveJessop Even without the class `G`, virtual inheritance is necessary to allow for future evolution.  (It's interesting that the only multiple inheritance Java allows is of interfaces, and it is the equivalent of virtual inheritance in C++.)

Answer (score 2):

It is difficult to give you design advices without knowing the exact *semantics* of your classes (letters are just symbols, so one must assume those inheritance relations are OK, while they may not be).

Just looking at the formal organization of your model, I would say you could add a virtual function to `A`, which both `D` and `E` would override. Those overrides would then delegate the implementation to `F::foo()`.

```
class A { 
public:
    virtual void bar() { }; // Maybe make this pure if A is abstract
    // ...
};

// ...

class D : public C, public F { 
public:
    virtual void bar() { /* ... */ f::foo(); /* ... */ }
    // ...
};

class E : public B, public F { 
public:
    virtual void bar() { /* ... */ f::foo(); /* ... */ }
    // ...
};
```

Comment: That pollutes the interface `A` with the functionality of `F`.  If this is acceptable, then just add all of the virtual functions of `F` to `A`, and forget about `F`.

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing the roles of the different classes, it's hard to
say, but if `A` and `F` are interfaces (likely the case), then
given an `A*`, the correct way to ask whether the object also
supports the interface `F` is `dynamic_cast<F*>`.  This gives
you a pointer to the `F` interface, if it is supported, and
a null pointer otherwise.

Beyond that, you might reflect whether the `F` interface extends
the `A` interface, or whether it is completely unrelated.  If it
is an extension, then `F` should probably derive from `A`; when
creating an object known to implement the extended interface,
you assign its address to an `F*`, and avoid all future casts.
(In general, don't assign to an `A*` until you reach a point
where some of the objects pointed to will *not* implement `F`.)
So you end up with something like:

```
//  interfaces...
class A {};
class F : public virtual A {};

//  implementations of A...
class C : public virtual A {};
class B : public virtual A {};

//  implementations of F (and also A, of course)
class E : public C, public virtual F {};
class D : public B, public virtual F {};
```

Note that when deriving from an interface, it is generally
a good idea to make the derivation virtual.  (In this case, it
is required for all derivations of `A`.  But since the same
pattern can repeat at another level, with some new class
extending the interface of `F`, it's generally simpler just to
adopt the rule: derivation from an interface is virtual.)

If `F` is truly unrelated to `A`, then you might even ask what
one class is doing implementing both.  Or if it makes sense that
some (many?) implementations of `A` also implement `F`, you
might consider providing access to `F` as part of the interface
of `A`: say a virtual function `F* A::getF() { return NULL; }`;
classes which also implement `F` will override this function
with something like `F* E::getF() { return this; }`.

Comment: I agree with all of this. Our two answers start in the same place and then offer slightly different options from the realm of possibilities depending on the real details of these classes. The rule that "derivation from interfaces is virtual" is important.

Comment: @SteveJessop Yes.  It's interesting to note that you are the only other answerer whol mentions virtual inheritance.  Can it be that we are the only two who use C++ as an OO language (among other paradigms).  (We also seem to be the only two who thought of `A` and `F` as interfaces.)

Comment: Yeah, it's interesting about the interfaces. I don't think all C++ programmers, even those using dynamic polymorphism, really distinguish between interfaces and other bases. To me, the fact that `A*` is passed around and that the receiving code wants to call a function of `F`, means that `A` and `F` *are* interfaces (or if `F` is a mixin then still `Foo` needs to be in some interface, which we should add). If they also have some implementation tangled up in them, well, that might be unfortunate from a code organization POV but it doesn't stop them being interfaces :-)

Comment: @SteveJessop Some code is usual in an interface, if you're using programming by contract.  The (pure) virtual functions should be private, with asserts of the pre- and post-conditions and the class invariants in the non-virtual public functions which define the interface, and forward to the private virtual functions.

Comment: Agreed. I don't claim to have a formal definition of the difference between "implementation" and "framework/boilerplate", but I mostly know it when I see it.

Comment: @SteveJessop One important detail: the interfaces, which we're inheriting virtually, never contain any non-static data members.  Which means that the default constructor is trivial, needn't be written, _and_ can be called from most derived classes that don't even know the interface exists in the hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

If `F` is *just* an implementation detail then you should do what @AndyProwl has said. Create a virtual function in the base class `A`.

If `F` *isn't* just an implementation detail, an alternative is to keep a lists of objects you want to deal with as `F`s, and objects you want to deal with as `A`s. Again, as Andy says, this will depend upon the semantics of your situation.

```
vector<F*> effs;
vector<A*> ehs;

A* a;
F* f;
if(condition) {
    E* e = new E();
    a = e;
    f = e;
}
else {
    D* d = new D();
    a = d;
    f = d;
}

effs.push_back(f);
ehs.push_back(a);

for(A* a: ehs) {
    a->bar();
}
for(F* f: effs) {
    f->foo();
}
```

Comment: If `F` is just an implementation detail (e.g. `F` is a concrete class which provides some common implementation), this is the mixin pattern, and he doesn't need (and should never have) a pointer to `F`.

Comment: @JamesKanze Yes, that's what I meant. If `F` isn't an implementation detail an alternative is... I will update.